# Method return a task, how get the return-value?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Lets say I have this code that calls a service and returns a task:

```
 public async Task<List<string>> GetList()
        {

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost9999/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/listofstrings");

                var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var myStr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(json);
                var list = new List<string>(myStr);


            return list;
        }
```

If this methpd simply returned a list of strings I could have done something like this:

```
var myList = new List<String>();
myList = GetList()
```

How can i get a similar result with the Task? Am i thinking about this the wrong way maybe? Surely I should be able to assign the result of the method (a list of strings) to `myList`?

Comment: You need to `await` it.

Comment: Exactly, `async` bubbles upwards, you have to `await` on it in any place you want it actually materialized.

Comment: This must be the second thing you read about async/await **if** you read about it.

Comment: I was trying to call the method from the ctor...Realise now that its not possible. Thank you all.

Comment: @Wranglerino In that case, [this blog post of mine](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) may help.

Comment: Aha! Looks very interesting and seems to be what im looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `await` to get the result of an `async` method:

```
var myList = await GetList();
```

To use `await` the method that you call `GetList` from should be `async` too.If it's not you can use `.Result` property, but this will block the execution:

```
var myList = GetList().Result;
```

Answer (score 1):

You `await` it, like this:

```
var myList = new List<String>();
myList = await GetList();
```

Note that according to the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx), `GetList` should have an `Async` suffix, which tips off developers that it should be `await`ed:

```
var myList = new List<String>();
myList = await GetListAsync();
```

And, of course, creating a new list just to throw it away is silly:

```
var myList = await GetListAsync();
```

Comment: Why create a `List` just to throw it away on the next line?

Comment: @EdS.: My initial code mirrors the op's sample code, to show the minimal code change necessary to grasp the basic concept of `await`. Later in my answer I point out that there's no point to creating a list that is thrown away.

Comment: @EdS.: From my machine's perspective, I edited before you commented. Distributed software FTW! :)