# universal windows app , making a WebRequest Method = GET

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10

Does anyone know how to get the WebResponse ?? the method GetResponse() is obsolet, btw it's windows universal app.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("myuri");
HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("name", "value");
httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.TryParseAdd("application/json");
webrequest.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse response = webrequest.GetResponseAsync();
StreamReader streamReader1 = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
```

solved:

solved with this:  private async void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

```
        response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        outputView.Text = "";

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("name", "value");

        // The value of 'InputAddress' is set by the user and is therefore untrusted input. 
        // If we can't create a valid URI, 
        // We notify the user about the incorrect input.

        Uri resourceUri = new Uri("myuri")


        string responseBodyAsText;


        try
        {
            response = await httpClient.GetAsync(resourceUri);

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            responseBodyAsText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)

        {
            // Need to convert int HResult to hex string
            statusText.Text = "Error = " + ex.HResult.ToString("X") +
                "  Message: " + ex.Message;
            responseBodyAsText = "";
        }





        // Format the HTTP response to display better
        responseBodyAsText = responseBodyAsText.Replace("<br>", Environment.NewLine);
        outputView.Text = responseBodyAsText;
```

Comment: the GetResponseASync() doesn't work :(

Comment: Yeah it does, if you lowercase the S. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's also quite unclear why you're mixing `HttpClient` and `HttpWebRequest`. If you search the web, MSDN or this site for "Universal app make web request", you'll find plenty of examples (first hit: [MSDN: How to connect to an HTTP server using Windows.Web.Http (HTML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn469430.aspx)).

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: @CodeCaster if you look the code it is lowercased the S thanks, also the link you shared it's for js and i'm using c# if you know another link it would be useful for me thank you a lot

Comment: Check the top of the page: _"Language: HTML | XAML"_. Click the XAML button for C# and C++ examples. And if you look at [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) you'll see you need to include all relevant details in your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Method return a task, how get the return-value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033094/method-return-a-task-how-get-the-return-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the `await` keyword.

```
HttpWebResponse response = await webrequest.GetResponseAsync();
```

Comment: adding await it says:

Comment: Error CS4033 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

Comment: @JacintRomero what don't you understand about that error message? in WinRT, things have to be async.

Comment: i don't understand why the await not works if the method is async , thanks

Comment: *your* method has to be async as well. that's what the error is stating.

Comment: What i'm trying to do is make the request to a server (of my company) to get the coordinates to add pushpins in determinated geopoints , i'm on an practices by the way